# a few days ago, Windows started popping up message CAPS LOCK ON or CAPS LOCK OFF every time I press Caps Lock key

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard

I can't find a control in Settings to turn this off.

I have no idea why this started happening.

OS. WINDOWS 10 PRO
Same DELL Precision laptop for a year

[image]

Comment: Look for  Dell Hot Key App.  I have such an App on my Lenovo machines and it puts up this indicator.

Comment: Windows 10 does not have a built-in visual caps-lock alert (though it *does* have a "beep" tone alert). Open Task manager to see what third-party software is making this pop-up. As @John suggests, it might be from Dell, perhaps added during an OEM update, or it might be a third-party tool.